# Access nested array in next.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js, javascript-objects

I am using nextjs and apollo for the first time and I am simply trying to use `.map` to iterate over database results.

Here is my component code:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client"
import Link from "next/link"
import ErrorMessage from "../layout/ErrorMessage"

export const ALL_COURSES_QUERY = gql`
  query getCourses($limit: Int, $field: String!, $order: Order!) {
    courses(limit: $limit, sort: { field: $field, order: $order }) {
      courseFeed {
        id
        title
        videos {
          title
        }
        creator {
          id
          lastName
        }
        sections {
          title
        }
        ratings {
          id
        }
        deletedAt
      }
      pageInfoCourse {
        nextPageCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
`

export const allCoursesQueryVars = {
  limit: 10,
  field: "title",
  order: "ASC",
}

export default function CourseList() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ALL_COURSES_QUERY, {
    variables: allCoursesQueryVars,
  })

  if (error) return <ErrorMessage message="Error loading courses." />

  const { courses } = data
  console.log(courses) // see output below

  return (
    <section>
      <ul>
        {courses.map((course) => (  // this does not work
          <li key={course.id}>
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/courses/[slug]",
                query: { slug: course.slug },
              }}>
              <a>{course.title}</a>
            </Link>
            <p>{course.creator}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </section>
  )
}
```

**console output**

```
{
  __typename: 'CourseFeed',
  courseFeed: [
    {
      __typename: 'Course',
      id: '607c1f1201509f26b866cbba',
      title: 'Kurs Eins',
      videos: [Array],
      creator: [Object],
      sections: [Array],
      ratings: [Array],
      deletedAt: null
    }
  ],
  pageInfoCourse: {
    __typename: 'PageInfoCourse',
    nextPageCursor: null,
    hasNextPage: false
  }
}
```

**Error Message**

> TypeError: courses.map is not a function

I would like to iterate over the `courseFeed` array to use the course objects in my page. I would be very thankful for any kind of help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the data you have provided, you are trying to map over `courses` like it is an array, but it clearly isn't. `courses` is an object containing a property `courseFeed` which *is* an array. This should work:

```
<ul>
  {courses.courseFeed.map((course) => ( 
  {/* More stuff */}
</ul>
```

**Edit**

You've indicated in the comments that you are getting `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child` when you apply the above fix.

That error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. `course.creator` is neither a React element, string or undefined. It is an `object` (which we can see from the log message you posted in the question), which React can't use as a child element, which means the line

```
<p>{course.creator}</p>
```

is invalid.

Although the log message in your question doesn't give us any clue about the structure of that object, the error message in your comments rather helpfully does. `object with keys {__typename, id, lastName}`. I'm guessing you probably want to display the last name of the creator, so you'll need to amend that line to

```
<p>{course.creator.lastName}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! After adding this line I, unfortunately, get the following error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__typename, id, lastName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Would you have any suggestion how I could resolve this?

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much!! You did not just resolve the problem but also made me understand where I went wrong!

Comment: @kampfkuchen happy to help :)